# Can I Allow my RouteTemplate to Being With an '/' Character?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller

I have the following method within my API controller in an AngularJS WebAPI/MVC project:

```
        [Route("GetRecordByID/{metricID:string}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Metric_Approval_Data))]
    [HttpGet]
    public Metric_Approval_Data GetRecordByID(string metricID)
    {
        Metric_Approval_Data arecord = null;
        try
        {
            arecord = dbContext.Metric_Approval_Data.Where(x => x.Metric_ID == metricID).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            arecord = null;
        }

        return arecord;
    }
```

This method should work correctly however when I build and run my project I am met with the following error:

**System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=The route template '/api/Record/GetRecordByID/{metricID:string}' on the action named 'GetRecordByID' cannot start with a '/' character.**

Currently I am unable to find a fix or some documentation for this Issue and was wondering if there is a simple workaround for this or I need to use a CAST at some point?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: i think they need start with `~/` in asp, but careful! a leading slash generally means the route is relative to the root(your domain)! otherwise it would usually be relative to the controller route or something. so, changing that might change the routes to your actions!

Comment: @PatrickBeynio so changing the controller route could be a better idea but it may cause further issues?